# Why are primitive types not returned as references in rust?

Tags: rust

Why is it that I always see functions returning primitive types
`u64, u32, u8` but not as often as references?

For example `fn foo() -> &u32`

Is it cheaper to just move these smaller types without using references / mutable references?

Comment: A reference is just a number.

Comment: For small [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) types that fit in one or two registers, it's just as efficient to dereference beforehand and pass them as values. Doing so simplifies the usage of such functions by eliminating the need for borrow checking.

Comment: @Schwern could you expand more on this? So let's say I had a more complex type I was returning , are you saying that under the hood it's just some number pointing to memory? this makes sense to me. if I return a reference to a number, it introduces another set of numbers for the references thus making it less efficient?

Answer (score 3):

The question is not *why* functions return values and not references, but *what* are they returning? And more specifically who is the *owner* of what they return. If some function creates a value and wants to give you that, then it semantically gives an ownership of it to you. If this value already exists somewhere else and has an owner function *could* return a reference to it so that you *borrow* this value. Note that giving `&i32` has not much benefits over giving `i32`, since this type is `Copy`.

You can read more about ownership in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) chapter of Tho Book.